# How to enqueue sequential coroutines blocks

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

### What I'm trying to do

I have an app that's using Room with Coroutines to save search queries in the database. It's also possible to add search suggestions and later on I retrieve this data to show them on a list. I've also made it possible to "pin" some of those suggestions.

My data structure is something like this:

```
@Entity(
        tableName = "SEARCH_HISTORY",
        indices = [Index(value = ["text"], unique = true)]
)
data class Suggestion(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "suggestion_id")
    val suggestionId: Long = 0L,
    val text: String,
    val type: SuggestionType,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "insert_date")
    val insertDate: Calendar
)

enum class SuggestionType(val value: Int) {
    PINNED(0), HISTORY(1), SUGGESTION(2)
}
```

I have made the "text" field unique to avoid repeated suggestions with different states/types. E.g.: A suggestion that's a pinned item and a previously queried text.

My Coroutine setup looks like this:

```
private val parentJob: Job = Job()

private val IO: CoroutineContext
    get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.IO

private val MAIN: CoroutineContext
    get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Main

private val COMPUTATION: CoroutineContext
    get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Default
```

And my DAOs are basically like this:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(obj: Suggestion): Long

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(objList: List<Suggestion>): List<Long>
```

I also have the following public functions to insert the data into the database:

```
fun saveQueryToDb(query: String, insertDate: Calendar) {
    if (query.isBlank()) {
        return
    }
    val suggestion = Suggestion(
            text = query,
            insertDate = insertDate,
            type = SuggestionType.HISTORY
    )
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        suggestionDAO.insert(suggestion)
    }
}

fun addPin(pin: String) {
    if (pin.isBlank()) {
        return
    }
    val suggestion = Suggestion(
            text = pin,
            insertDate = Calendar.getInstance(),
            type = SuggestionType.PINNED
    )
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        suggestionDAO.insert(suggestion)
    }
}

fun addSuggestions(suggestions: List<String>) {
    addItems(suggestions, SuggestionType.SUGGESTION)
}

private fun addItems(items: List<String>, suggestionType: SuggestionType) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        return
    }

    CoroutineScope(COMPUTATION).launch {
        val insertDate = Calendar.getInstance()
        val filteredList = items.filterNot { it.isBlank() }
        val suggestionList = filteredList.map { History(text = it, insertDate = insertDate, suggestionType = suggestionType) }
        withContext(IO) {
            suggestionDAO.insert(suggestionList)
        }
    }
}
```

There are also some other methods, but let's focus on the ones above.

**EDIT:** All of the methods above are part of a lib that I made, they're are not made `suspend` because I don't want to force a particular type of programming to the user, like forcing to use Rx or Coroutines when using the lib.

### The problem

Let's say I try to add a list of suggestions using the `addSuggestions()` method stated above, and that I also try to add a pinned suggestion using the `addPin()` method. The pinned text is also present in the suggestion list.

```
val list = getSuggestions() // Getting a list somewhere
addSuggestions(list)
addPin(list.first())
```

When I try to do this, sometimes the pin is added first and then it's overwritten by the suggestion present in the list, which makes me think I might've been dealing with some sort of race condition. Since the `addSuggestions()` method has more data to handle, and both methods will run in parallel, I believe the `addPin()` method is completing first.

Now, my Coroutines knowledge is pretty limited and I'd like to know if there's a way to enqueue those method calls and make sure they'll execute in the exact same order I invoked them, that must be strongly guaranteed to avoid overriding data and getting funky results later on. How can I achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd follow the Go language slogan "Don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating", that means instead of maintaining atomic variables or jobs and trying to synchronize between them, model your operations as messages and use Coroutines [actors](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/actor.html) to handle them.

```
sealed class Message {
   data AddSuggestions(val suggestions: List<String>) : Message()
   data AddPin(val pin: String) : Message()
}
```

And in your class

```
private val parentScope = CoroutineScope(Job())

private val actor = parentScope.actor<Message>(Dispatchers.IO) {
        for (msg in channel) {
            when (msg) {
                is Message.AddSuggestions -> TODO("Map to the Suggestion and do suggestionDAO.insert(suggestions)")
                is Message.AddPin -> TODO("Map to the Pin and do suggestionDAO.insert(pin)")
            }
        }
    }

fun addSuggestions(suggestions: List<String>) {
    actor.offer(Message.AddSuggestions(suggestions))
}

fun addPin(pin: String) {
    actor.offer(Message.AddPin(pin))
}
```

By using actors you'll be able to queue messages and they will be processed in FIFO order.

Comment: This achieved what I was expecting, but I needed to make one minor modification: The default capacity is zero, so if I ever tried to post more than one message at a time it would block it. I changed to an arbitrary number (say 10) and it worked :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By default when you call `.launch{}`, it launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread and returns a reference to the coroutine as a **Job**. The coroutine is canceled when the resulting job is canceled.

It doesn't care or wait for other parts of your code it just runs.

But you can pass a parameter to basically tell it to run immediately or wait for other Coroutine to finish(LAZY).

For Example:

```
       val work_1 = CoroutineScope(IO).launch( start = CoroutineStart.LAZY ){
       
              //do dome work
        }

       val work_2 = CoroutineScope(IO).launch( start = CoroutineStart.LAZY ){
            //do dome work
            work_1.join()
        }

        val work_3 = CoroutineScope(IO).launch(  ) {
            //do dome work
            work_2.join()
        }
```

When you execute the above code first **work_3** will finish and invoke **work_2** when inturn invoke **Work_1** and so on,

***The summary of coroutine start options is:***

**DEFAULT** -- immediately schedules coroutine for execution according to its context

**LAZY** -- starts coroutine lazily, only when it is needed

**ATOMIC** -- atomically (in a non-cancellable way) schedules coroutine for execution according to its context

**UNDISPATCHED** -- immediately executes coroutine until its first suspension point in the current thread.

So by default when you call `.launch{}` `start = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT` is passed because it is default parameter.

Comment: But what if I wanted to call work_2 before work_1 instead of work_1 -> work_2? I can't know beforehand which order will they be called by the programmer. Both situations can happen in the same app.

Comment: First, there was typo in my answer, it is work_3 -> work_2 -> work_1. Just like i say if you want to prioritize **work_2** over **work_1**, you pass **work_1.launch( start = CoroutineStart.LAZY ){ }** which will make it wait until you call **work_1.join()**, If you want **work_2** to be invoked immediatly, you don't pass any argument( it is by default set to CoroutineStart.DEFAULT )  but you can call  **work_1.join()** after it finish it's work to start **work_1**.

Comment: Ok, first of all, thanks for your attention! This misunderstanding was my fault since I forgot to mention that those methods are API calls and are part of a lib, so I have to stick to a single solution and therefore can't know which order my users will call the works. That way I can't prioritize the methods beforehand. Any thoughts? :(

Answer (score 1):

Don't launch coroutines from your database or repository. Use suspending functions and then switch dispatchers like:

```
suspend fun addPin(pin: String) {
    ...
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        suggestionDAO.insert(suggestion)
    }
}
```

Then from your `ViewModel` (or `Activity`/`Fragment`) make the call:

```
fun addSuggestionsAndPinFirst(suggestions: List<Suggestion>) {
    myCoroutineScope.launch {
        repository.addSuggestions(suggestions)
        repository.addPin(suggestions.first())
    }
}
```

Why do you have a separate `addPin()` function anyways? You can just modify a suggestion and then store it:

```
fun pinAndStoreSuggestion(suggestion: Suggestion) {
    myCoroutineScope.launch {
        repository.storeSuggestion(suggestion.copy(type = SuggestionType.PINNED)
    }
}
```

Also be careful using a `Job` like that. If any coroutine fails all your coroutines will be cancelled. Use a `SupervisorJob` instead. Read more on that [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/exceptions-in-coroutines-ce8da1ec060c).

Disclaimer: I do not approve of the solution below. I'd rather use an old-fashioned `ExecutorService` and `submit()` my `Runnable`'s

So if you really want to synchronize your coroutines in a way that the first function called is also the first one to write to your database. (I'm not sure it is guaranteed since your DAO functions are also suspending and Room uses it's own threads too). Try something like the following unit test:

```
class TestCoroutineSynchronization {

    private val jobId = AtomicInteger(0)
    private val jobToRun = AtomicInteger(0)
    private val jobMap = mutableMapOf<Int, () -> Unit>()
    
    @Test
    fun testCoroutines() = runBlocking {
        first()
        second()

        delay(2000) // delay so our coroutines finish
    }

    private fun first() {
        val jobId = jobId.getAndIncrement()
        CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            delay(1000) // intentionally delay your first coroutine
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                submitAndTryRunNextJob(jobId) { println(1) }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun second() {
        val jobId = jobId.getAndIncrement()
        CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob()).launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            submitAndTryRunNextJob(jobId) { println(2) }
        }
    }

    private fun submitAndTryRunNextJob(jobId: Int, action: () -> Unit) {
        synchronized(jobMap) {
            jobMap[jobId] = action
            tryRunNextJob()
        }
    }

    private fun tryRunNextJob() {
        var action = jobMap.remove(jobToRun.get())
        while (action != null) {
            action()
            action = jobMap.remove(jobToRun.incrementAndGet())
        }
    }
}
```

So what I do on each call is increment a value (jobId) that is later used to prioritize what action to run first. Since you are using suspending function you probably need to add that modifier to the action submitted too (e.g. `suspend () -> Unit`).

Comment: I've simplified the code to put in this question, it's not launched there. As for why I'm not using suspend in the other methods, they're exposed API methods and I don't want to force someone to explicitly use coroutines outside that class (it's a lib). And I have different methods for addPin/addSuggestion/saveQuery to avoid exposing the enum and make the API clearer.

Comment: About the Job, I didn't know that it would cancel in that situation, thanks for the tip! I was trying to mimic the CompositeDisposable behavior from Rx.

Comment: Aha, so if you want to run them sequential you either need synchronization or rather queue them on the same single thread. The former option is a lot harder, because you need the function that is called first, to execute first on your IO dispatcher.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Well the problem with using a single dispatcher is that a coroutine still can get suspended and another can take over execution, so I'm unsure if it guarantees the execution order you want.

Comment: Easiest solution that comes to mind is using the old fashioned `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and `submit()` your 'jobs'. I'm going to post a new answer with an attempt to try and use synchronization.